# React-redux dispatcher not being connected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a component who needs to call an action dispatcher, but when i trigger it i got an "undefined is not a function" error.

I'm using react-redux, redux-persist and redux-thunk.

All my others actions when called works perfectly.

UserActions.js

```
export const updateProfile = (user, token) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      axios()
        .then(response => {
          getUpdateProfileSuccess(response.data, dispatch);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          getUpdateProfileError(error.response, dispatch);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      getUpdateProfileError(error.response, dispatch);
    }
  };
};

const getUpdateProfileSuccess = (data, dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
    data
  });
};

const getUpdateProfileError = (error, dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_PROFILE_ERROR,
    error
  });
};
```

My component.js

```
import...
import { updateProfile } from "../../../../Actions/UserActions";

class CardInfo extends Component {
  _handleUpdateProfile = () => {
    let user = {...};
    this.props.updateProfile(user, this.props.token);
  }
  render() {
    return (...)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  token: state.UserReducer.token,
  user_data: state.UserReducer.user_data
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { updateProfile }
)(CardInfo);
```

When i debug the code i get this error:

> message: "updateProfile is not defined"
>
> stack: "ReferenceError: updateProfile is not defined
>       at eval (eval at CardInfo._this._handleUpdateProfile (blob:http://localhost:8081/41e77cd1-d0ff-413b-a32f-dfca9ee6061e:151091:21),
>   :1:1)
>       at Object.CardInfo._this._handleUpdateProfile [as onPress] (blob:http://localhost:8081/41e77cd1-d0ff-413b-a32f-dfca9ee6061e:151091:21)
>       at Object.Basic._this._handlePress [as onPress] (blob:http://localhost:8081/41e77cd1-d0ff-413b-a32f-dfca9ee6061e:124999:21)
>       at Object.touchableHandlePress (blob:http://localhost:8081/41e77cd1-d0ff-413b-a32f-dfca9ee6061e:46460:40)
>       at Object._performSideEffectsForTransition (blob:http://localhost:8081/41e77cd1-d0ff-413b-a32f-dfca9ee6061e:45131:16)
>       at Object._receiveSignal (blob:http://localhost:8081/41e77cd1-d0ff-413b-a32f-dfca9ee6061e:45060:14)
>       at Object.touchableHandleResponderRelease (blob:http://localhost:8081/41e77cd1-d0ff-413b-a32f-dfca9ee6061e:44939:12)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (blob:http://localhost:8081/41e77cd1-d0ff-413b-a32f-dfca9ee6061e:7899:16)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (blob:http://localhost:8081/41e77cd1-d0ff-413b-a32f-dfca9ee6061e:7990:37)
>       at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (blob:http://localhost:8081/41e77cd1-d0ff-413b-a32f-dfca9ee6061e:7994:31)"

Comment: I would check twice if this is the right path `"../../../../Actions/UserActions"` cause as you put it the files don't even seem to have the same name (`Action.js` and `UserActions`).

Comment: @CrazyBarney that's the right path, i miss the name sorry.

Comment: Could you try to have 
`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CardInfo);`
with
`const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateProfile: ((user, token) => dispatch(updateProfile(user, token))
    };
};`

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK you should add `props` as an argument to the constructor.

```
class CardInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  ...
}
```